# Event using ng-click is not working?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

> I am new to angularjs in this angular code i want to increase the
>   value of the fib variable. For this i made a function named as fibapp
>   . here i have the html and angular code below please help to run it.

**ang.js**

`

```
var mod=angular.module("myModule",[]);
 mod.controller("events",function($scope)
 {
    fib=0;
    $scope.fib=fib;
    $scope.fibapp=function(fib)
    {
      fib++;
    }
 }
);
```

`

**HTML code using the Above angular code**

`

```
<html>
       <head>
             <script src="E:/angular.min.js"></script>
             <script src="E:/ang.js"></script>
       </head>
       <body ng-app="myModule">
           <div ng-controller="events">
               <p>{{fib}}</p>
               <input type="button" ng-click="fibapp(fib)">
            </div>
       </body>
</html>
```

`

Comment: I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
var mod=angular.module("myModule",[]);
mod.controller("events",function($scope)
{
   fib=0;
   $scope.fib=fib;
   $scope.fibapp=function(fib)
   {
      $scope.fib++;
   }
}
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/11942/)